# Not saving to local storage

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck on what I have done while playing around with the code. I had it saving to local storage but now its not. Could someone help me troubleshoot this

```
<form name="todoForm" action="" method="get">
    Reminder : <input type="text" name="ReminderInput" id="ReminderInput"><br />
    Date: <input type="datetime-local" name="DateInput" id="DateInput"><br />
    Extra Information : <input type="text" name="InfoInput" id="InfoInput"><br />
    <button onclick="storeValues(reminder)" type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    function storeValues(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let storedReminders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Reminders")) || [];

        const newReminderDetails = {
            ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
            DateInput: document.getElementById('DateInput').value,
            InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value
        }
        storedReminders.push(newReminderDetails);
        localStorage.setItem("Reminders", JSON.stringify(storedReminders));

        console.log('storedReminders', storedReminders);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is reminder in button onclick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write event  rather then reminder

```
<button onclick="storeValues(event)" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't do anything wrong but there is a tiny mistake which is we don't do click event on forms instead we using a submit event. so here is my solution
HTML Code:

```
<form id="todoForm" action="" method="get">
        Reminder : <input type="text" name="ReminderInput" id="ReminderInput"><br />
        Date: <input type="datetime-local" name="DateInput" id="DateInput"><br />
        Extra Information : <input type="text" name="InfoInput" id="InfoInput"><br />
        <button type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS Code

```
function storeValues(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let storedReminders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Reminders")) || [];
    const newReminderDetails = {
        ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
        InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value
    }
    storedReminders.push(newReminderDetails);
    localStorage.setItem("Reminders", JSON.stringify(storedReminders));
    console.log('storedReminders', storedReminders);    
    }
document.getElementById("todoForm").addEventListener("submit",storeValues );
```

Comment: the sane you just need to add it as you did before